# Get service account details and their usages in SharePoint Environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, service-account, powershell-script

We have lots of service accounts in our SharePoint environment, now we are planning to delete the unwanted service accounts from our environment to keep the environment clean. So, I was checking whether is there any PowerShell script or any other tool where the particular accounts are being used, so, that I can decide whether the particular account can be deleted or not?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we can only Go to the SharePoint Central Administration as admin>Security>Configure service accounts>select the related services, it will display Service Account it's using.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to write such a script because it's hard to come up with an exhaustive list of all places where SharePoint accounts might be used except SharePoint itself. In older farms, they are typically used for more than just "SharePoint only" purposes.

It would be nice start to check at least:

- IIS application pool accounts
- Windows services on SharePoint Servers
- Central Administration - Security - Configure service accounts
- SQL Server - Security - Logins
- Windows Task scheduler